# Как с таймера вытянуть время?

Tags: c#

Как с таймера вытянуть время за отработанный промежуток времени ?

Интересуют секунды и миллисекунды

```
        private void Start(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void Stop(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            textBox1.AppendText("" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private DateTime startTime;

    private void Start(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        startTime = DateTime.Now;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void Stop(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        textBox1.AppendText((DateTime.Now - startTime).ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```